# How do i make a html table not have dynamic columns that change size in width depending on the amount of data in a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a table that has equally sized columns which wont change depending on the length of the table data

[image]

In the picture the data under the heading "Titel" moves the second column further to the right compared to the other tables where "Titel" is shorter. This behaviour is not wanted but it seems to be the default.

I tried padding the first column but it doesn't change the behaviour at all.
How can i achive a fixed size  that doesnt push other columns away?

Here is an example code which gives the unwanted behaviour

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 15px;
}

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Border Spacing</h2>
    <p>Border spacing specifies the space between the cells.</p>
    
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried setting width on the table and its columns, and also padding the table but it doesn't work.

Comment: Set an absolute width on the columns. But please provide some example code, showing how you have it now and what you've tried.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added some example code that one can play around with, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4.0 you can use the sizing utilities classes for widths:

```
<thead>
     <tr>
           <th class="w-25">25</th>
           <th class="w-50">50</th>
           <th class="w-25">25</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

You can also use `d-inline-block` to prevent the default setting of `display:flex`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using style="table-layout:fixed" on the table and using bootstrap cols on the table headers.